# Entries in me/feed from current user to group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

Recently me/feed started to include entries sent by current user to groups.
The id field is invalid for those entries and simply returns "false".

Changing the first part of the id to the one mentioned in "to" gives a valid entry.
It could be a good workaround except there is no way to immediately know which posts are normal and which posts are to Groups.

I did notice that on posts to groups there is an extra field 'version' that is not documented. Anyone knows what this field means?

Example entry:

```
  ...
  "id": "1188060277_343671429042688", 
  "from": {
    "name": "My Name", 
    "id": "1188060277"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "version": 1, 
        "name": "Group Name", 
        "id": "194744830602016"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

groups

The Groups that the user belongs to.

user_groups or friends_groups.

An array of objects containing the version(old-0 or new Group-1), name, id, administrator (if user is the administrator of the Group) and bookmark_order(at what place in the list of group bookmarks on the homepage, the group shows up for the user).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/